# Angle between edges in a square pyramid

Tags: geometry

[image: The pyramid]

How do you calculate the missing angle? I couldn't figure it out. This is not homework, just a math practice question that I made up to test myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First proof by analytical geometry**.

Let

- $A(1,1,0),B(1,-1,0),C(-1,-1,0),D(-1,1,0)$ be the basis' vertices,
- $S(0,0,z)$ be the summit, with unknown $z$ and
- $a=SA=SB=SC=SD$.
- $\alpha$ be the unknown angle between $\vec{SA}$ and $\vec{SC}$.

Then $\tag{1} \cases{\vec{SA}=(1,1,0)-(0,0,z)=(1,1,-z)\\ \vec{SB}=(1,-1,0)-(0,0,z)=(1,-1,-z)\\ \vec{SC}=(-1,-1,0)-(0,0,z)=(-1,-1,-z)} $

A first consequence is that $\tag{2}a^2=\vec{SA}^2=2+z^2.$

Now, using the two forms of the dot product:

$$\tag{3}\vec{SA}.\vec{SB}=\cases{\|SA\|\|SB\|\cos(ASB)=a^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a^2\\(1) \times (1) + (1) \times (-1)+(-z) \times (-z)=z^2}$$

giving : $\tag{4}a^2=\sqrt{2}z^2$

With (2} and {4}, we deduce the values $\tag{5}\cases{z^2=2+2\sqrt{2}\\a^2=4+2\sqrt{2}}$

Expressing as in (3), $\vec{SA}.\vec{SC}$ in two ways, that the unknown angle $\alpha$ is such that, using (1),

$$\tag{4}\vec{SA}.\vec{SC}=\cases{\cos(\alpha)a^2\\(1) \times (-1) + (1) \times (-1)+(-z) \times (-z)=z^2-2}$$
Thus $\cos(\alpha)=\dfrac{z^2-2}{a^2}$. Using (4), one obtains:

$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{4+2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}-1.$

The final result is $\alpha=acos(\sqrt{2}-1)\approx 1.14372 rad.$

i.e. close to $55^{\circ}1/2$.

**Second proof by law of cosines** (applied twice) (see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines))

We take the same conventions as in the previous proof.

In triangle SAB: $\ AB^2=SA^2+SB^2-2 SA.SB \cos(\pi/4).$

giving $2^2=a^2+a^2-2a^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$ out of which we obtain

$$\tag{5}a^2=2(2+\sqrt{2}).$$

In triangle SAC: $\ AC^2=SA^2+SC^2-2 SA.SC \cos(\alpha)$

giving $(2 \sqrt{2})^2=a^2+a^2-2a^2 \cos(\alpha).$

or $\tag{6}4=a^2(1- \cos(\alpha)).$

Using (5) in (6), we are able to deduce

$$\cos(\alpha)=1-\frac{4}{a^2}=1-\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{2}}=1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}=1-\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)=\sqrt{2}-1$$ as before.

Comment: could you explain it in an easier way?

Comment: If you work by analytical geometry, you have to folllow these steps. But there is another methd that I am going to add to my answer.

Comment: I have added the second solution, using the law of cosines.

Comment: Is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the side S=1 and use trigonometry
[image: Let the side S be 1]

Comment: [+1] Simple solution ! The only regret one can have is that you don't wait the end to use numerical approximation. For example $\sin(22.5^{\circ}=\sin(\pi/8)=\sqrt{2}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Two neighboring oblique sides have directions $(1,1,h)$ and $(-1,1,h)$ and must be such that

$$\cos\alpha=\cos\frac\pi4=\frac{(1,1,h)}{\sqrt{2+h^2}}\cdot\frac{(-1,1,h)}{\sqrt{2+h^2}}=\frac{h^2}{h^2+2}.$$

Then taking to opposite sides,

$$\cos\beta=\frac{(1,1,h)}{\sqrt{2+h^2}}\cdot\frac{(-1,-1,h)}{\sqrt{2+h^2}}=\frac{h^2-2}{h^2+2}=2\frac{h^2}{h^2+2}-1.$$

Hence

$$\cos\beta=\sqrt2-1.$$

---

We can also perform the computation using spherical coordinates to represent unit vectors $$(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\phi).$$

Then as above, with $\theta=0,\pi/2$ and$\pi$,
$$\cos\alpha=(\cos\phi,0,\sin\phi)\cdot(0,\cos\phi,\sin\phi)=\sin^2\phi,$$

$$\cos\beta=(\cos\phi,0,\sin\phi)\cdot(-\cos\phi,0,\sin\phi)=\sin^2\phi-\cos^2\phi=2\cos\alpha-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the angles, once you have the vectors corresponding to each side.
In your case, put the center of the base at the origin, call $h$ the height, determine what $h$ shall be in order to get $\pi /4$ as the given angle. Then you have all the vectors.